# How to use Angular build in Next.js

Tags: angular, next.js, micro-frontend

I want to render Angular application build in Next.js  component. where as Angular bundle can be import in next js project.

Angular bundle i have make copy in my Next.js  project but how to use that.

Any help would be appriciated in advance.